# Extending charjs interface with missing types

Tags: typescript, chart.js, typing

Im am trying to set scaleDefaults for chartjs. I am using the typings from  `@types/chart.js` v2.7.22.

```
Chart.scaleService.updateScaleDefaults('logarithmic', {
    ticks: {
        callback: function (tick: number, index: number, ticks: number[]) {
            // CODE
        }
    }
```

But this however gives an issue: `Property 'scaleService' does not exist on type 'typeof Char'`. If i cast this to `any` however it works fine.

But i dont wan to cast this to any so i'd wanted to extend the chartjs interface resulting in:

```
interface ChartExtended extends Chart { }

(Chart as ChartExtended).scaleService.updateScaleDefaults('logarithmic', {
    ticks: {
        callback: function (tick: number, index: number, ticks: number[]) {
            // CODE
        }
    }
```

But again i am confronted with type errors:

```
Type 'typeof Chart' cannot be converted to type 'ChartExtended'.
Property 'config' is misisng in type 'typeof Chart'
```

When i check the index.d.ts I notice that there is a seperate class def and a namespace def with the same name:

```
declare class Chart {
    static readonly Chart: typeof Chart;
    // Stuff
}

declare namespace Chart {
     // Stuff
}

export = Chart;
export as namespace Chart;
```

I want to create an interface that properly extends chart so that i can define scaleService.

I'd expect to defined the interface like:

```
interface ChartExtended extends Chart {
    scaleService?: ScaleService
}
```

Comment: What version of the @types are you using ?, I installed `npm install @types/chartjs` and see different types to the ones you say you have in `index.d.ts.`

Comment: @TitanCernicova-Dragomir I installed  2.7.22

Comment: Neverrmind, it should have been `npm install @types/chart.js`